# Open PDF with Edge in Fullscreen through Batch

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd, microsoft-edge

at the moment im trying to open a pdf file `%UserInputID%.pdf` in fullscreen but i dont quite get it to work.

At the moment im just doing `start "" /max "path\%UserInputID%.pdf"`.

I did find out about outdated workarounds with powershell that use `SendKeys` but as that is not completly supported anymore (?) i thought about using the startparameter of edge/chromium. But how? How to use `--start-fullscreen` as a parameter? Just appending it like -parameter `\%UserInputID%.pdf" ---start-fullscreen` does not work, neither does /parameter `\%UserInputID%.pdf" /--start-fullscreen`. Happy for every answer or hint.
*Edge is the standard pdf programm

*Edit / Addendum: After KJ's Answer I also figured

```
start "name" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --start-fullscreen file:///"path\%UserInputID%.pdf"
```

as a (partial) valid answer. Partial because if only a single (partial) instance of edge is still open (normal x doesnt do the job) it wont work, as it seem like it cant "start" in fullscreen if it is already open in non fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in your case  two ways to use MSEdge

The first as you know is if it is the default pdf application then it will use current edge profile to open the pdf so as you describe we can simply use

```
start "" /max "mydemo.pdf"
```

And Edge will use its default settings to display MyDemo.PDF in a window but will ignore the /MAX request.

It is the same if we call it directly

```
start "" /max msedge "file:///C:\mypath\mydemo.pdf"
```

However we can use it in Kiosk mode

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"  --kiosk --no-first-run --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen file:///C:\mypath\mydemo.pdf
```

if you wish you can also add a minute timer for auto release to normal mode but it is minutes not seconds

`--kiosk-idle-timeout-minutes=1`

as comment added to question you can also run the second session as

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --start-fullscreen --no-first-run --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen file:///C:\mypath\mydemo.pdf
```